# How to build ParseQuery by joining two or more tables or using inner queries?

Tags: android, parse-platform

I'm trying to build an application in which I need to build a ParseQuery something like

```
SELECT * FROM PHOTOS WHERE objectID NOT in (SELECT photo FROM HISTORY WHERE user = {currentUser})
```

Consider the Class:

```
PHOTOS:
*objectID
*photo(file)
*user(user object)

HISTORY
*objectID
*photo(PHOTOS pointer)
*user(user object)
```

Basically I need to get the photo(file) from PHOTOS table are not in the HISTORY table. How to build the query for this.?

Comment: please share both table structure your query seem to be wrong i need to check table structure

Comment: I need to develop a mechanism in which some images will be stored in the PHOTOS table and whenever user view that image a HISTORY record will be created. And the next time I should restrict the user from viewing the same photo by checking it is already viewed using HISTORY table. Can you suggest the best design for this using parse.

Comment: SELECT * FROM PHOTOS WHERE objectID NOT in (SELECT objectID  FROM HISTORY WHERE user = {currentUser})